# Draft-js: Losing cursor with non-editable entity components

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, draftjs, keyboard-navigation

I have an editor that is supposed to have entities with the props `name, color, start, end`. In the editor the text in positions denoted by `start` and `end` will be subsistuted by `name`, and it will be rendered by a custom component with `contentEditable=false`.

This works great with draftjs in general but there are a couple of issues:

- When moving the cursor with the keyboard arrows, the entities are skipped over, which is good. But when an entity is at the very end of the input and I try to move rightwards past it (either just with right arrow or with option or cmd + right) the cursor disappears and doesn't come back when I move left again.
- If I go right to the left of an entity and push shift + option + right arrow, the entity is selected as expected. But if I then press left arrow the cursor is also lost.

I could fix this by making sure there is always a whitespace after such a last entity, but that seems hacky and probably has edge cases.

Another option is to not use `contentEditable=false`, but that creates other issues with my actual app, which has a more complicated entity component including a dropdown, and I will have to manually make sure the user can't change text inside the entities etc.

Here is a reproduction of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-surf-st77i

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing here. Ended up moving to slate-js instead because it doesn't seem to have the same issue (and I could afford it, since it's a new project)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip!

Comment: JIC it's useful to someone else, I ran into this too trying to render some custom entities, the fix was to render the entity in such a way that the DOM structure matched the number of characters I wanted this entity to be. If you render an emoji for example, but using some funky image nested in a div, etc., I want this to be one character. So, render <span>{child}<spanA><img/></spanA></span>, where child is the single character with the entity applied. spanA here is a span with `user-select: none`. You can make the child `color: transparent` too, and `caret-color: black` to fix selection bhvr.